# Is xamp enought to execute php scripts?

Tags: php, xampp

I have only xampp 3.1.0 installed...And I want to execute php scripts..is xampp enought or is necessary to install another program? Thanks in advance, and sorry about my question, but a I a begginer and my php scripts does not execute only with xampp..and I dont know why?

Comment: What do you mean by "Php scripts does not executes"? Are you getting plain text php code in your browser?

Comment: yes, Iam getting the php code in my browser

Comment: Are you pointing your browser to `http://localhost/filename.php` or just opening the script as a file

Comment: Also have you started the Apache module?

Comment: Apache Service detected with wrong path
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache settings or
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager

Comment: 11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Problem detected!
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "httpd.exe"!
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:37:37 PM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port                                                            Can this be the problem?

Comment: do you have more than one set of XAMPP? did you install apache as standalone also?

Comment: No I did not install it as standalone....i have only one  xampp..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use xampp to create a local server and to process server side languages. This includes PHP. Please provide a bit of code.